# Observer pattern implementation with complete layer separation and testability, am I doing it right?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, observer-pattern

I have doubts regarding my implementation of observer pattern, but with complete separation of concerns.

Example below is not a real life code, but just an example of idea how I want to do it.

In my solution I have two project layers:

- Desktop layer (views, view models, models)
- Service library layer (with observers)

My view model is a subject subscribing the observers.

Code in VM:

```
interface ISubject
{
    void Subscribe(IObserverService observer);
    void Unsubscribe(IObserverService observer);
    void Notify();
}
public class MainWindowViewModel : ViewModelBase, ISubject
{
    private readonly IObserverService _observer1;
    private readonly IObserverService _observer2;
    private ArrayList _observers;

    public MainWindowViewModel(
    IObserver1 observer1,
    IObserver2 observer2)
    {
        _observer1 = observer1;
        _observer2 = observer2;

        ObserverCommand = new DelegateCommand(OnObserverCommand);

        InitProgram();
    }

    private void InitProgram()
    {
        _observers = new ArrayList();

        _observers.Add(_observer1);
        _observers.Add(_observer2);
    }

    public List<IObserverService> Observers { get; set; }

    private void OnSwitchCommand(object obj)
    {
        if (Jeden == true)
        {
            UiModel = _controlsService.SwitchOff();
        }
        else
        {
            UiModel = _controlsService.SwitchOn();
        }
    }

    private void OnObserverCommand(object obj)
    {
        SomeValue++;
    }

    public void Subscribe(IObserverService observer)
    {
        Observers.Add(observer);
    }

    public void Unsubscribe(IObserverService observer)
    {
        Observers.Remove(observer);
    }

    public void Notify()
    {
        Observers.ForEach(x => x.Update(SomeValue));
    }

    public ICommand ObserverCommand { get; private set; }

    private int _someValue;
    public int SomeValue
    {
        get => _someValue;
        set
        {
            _someValue = value;
            InformObservers();
        }
    }

    private void InformObservers()
    {
        foreach (IObserverService x in _observers)
        {
            x.Update(SomeValue);
        }
    }
}
```

And my observer in service layer is very simple. After `Update` call from the subject is displaying new `MessageBox`:

```
public interface IObserverService
{
    void Update(int someValue);
}
public class Observer1 : IObserver1, IObserverService
{
    public string ObserverName { get; private set; }
    public Observer1(string name)
    {
        this.ObserverName = name;
    }
    public void Update(int someValue)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("New value: " + someValue.ToString() + " for " + ObserverName);
    }
}
```

`Observer2` is same as above.

Right now I have doubts how my constructor supposed to look like, if I want to create a new observer with a name parameter, for example: `new Observer1("name1")` in this case, keeping separation, should my subject's ctor look like:

```
public MainWindowViewModel()
{
     _observerService = observerService;
     IObserverService observer1 = new ObserverService("name1");
     IObserverService observer2 = new ObserverService("name2");

     SwitchCommnad = new DelegateCommand(OnSwitchCommand);
     ObserverCommand = new DelegateCommand(OnObserverCommand);

     InitProgram();
}
```

Is it correct approach? Is it going to be testable? Or I have to inject IObserverService somehow?

Comment: Can't understand your .ctor, would you mind taking a look a it as is not correctly written? :)

Comment: so far you managed complete *obfuscation* of concerns. why do you even need observers? what problem are you trying to solve, which can't be done with INotifyPropertyChanged?

Comment: @Kaitiff you are right, corrected, thank you.

Comment: @ASh actually I wanted to learn using Observer. But do you think that most of the cases `INotifyPropertyChanged` is replacing it? And actually I am not sure how could I mock this observers.

Comment: Your code doesn't make sense. Why do you pass  observers to the observable via a constructor? Expose a subscribe method. There is no need to introduce a dependency on observers. Observers just get notified and are pretty useless for the observable (the view model in your case). By injecting observers via the constructor you introduce a unnecessary  dependency. Service and desktop layer can and should implement the same `IObserver` interface because the observable doesn't care who the observer is.

Comment: Also use Multicast Delegates and `event` to eliminate the collections and iterations. If you still want to go the the complicated way take a look at Microsoft Docs: [Observer Design Pattern](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/events/observer-design-pattern). .NET provides some generic interfaces to implement the pattern. At least you can learn from their implementation.

Comment: @BionicCode "Observers just get notified and are pretty useless for the observable" - very good poit. But in this case how to test that observer was notified? Should I mock it and test property update?

Comment: You can subscribe to the event from your test case and assert that your callback was invoked with the expected arguments.

Comment: To test the observer you can mock the observable and artificially raise an event (e,g using Moq.Raise`` of the Moq framework)

Comment: You can also use a mock (e.g. with Moq) to test the observable if it raises the event.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it makes sense, that MainWindowViewModel will receive some external observers via constructor:

```
public MainWindowViewModel(IObserver1 observer1, IObserver2 observer2)
{
    _observer1 = observer1;
    _observer2 = observer2;

    ObserverCommand = new DelegateCommand(OnObserverCommand);

    InitProgram();
}
```

when you create an instance of MainWindowViewModel (I assume, it will be used for MainWindowView DataContext), you will pass some real observers:

```
 IObserverService observer1 = new ObserverService("name1");
 IObserverService observer2 = new ObserverService("name2");
 var vm = new MainWindowViewModel(observer1, observer2);
 mainWindow.DataContext = vm;
```

no need for DI container here if dependencies can be resolved statically

similarly, for test you can have some `TestObserverService` (or IObserverService mock):

```
 IObserverService observer1 = new TestObserverService("name1");
 IObserverService observer2 = new TestObserverService("name2");
 var vm = new MainWindowViewModel(observer1, observer2);
```

MainWindowViewModel *might* create some IObserverServices, *if* it has properties worth observing from other objects in the application (e.g. related view models)

Comment: Ok, it makes sence. I was fixed, that mock supposed to be injected into the ctor, but as you write, I can factor some TestObserverService, or mock `IObserver2` && `IObserver1`, even if its not injected, right?

Comment: `public MainWindowViewModel(IObserver1 observer1, IObserver2 observer2)` is a constructor injection. you can provaide any implementation, or mock, in their places

Answer (score 1):

If you want to test your VM, follow IoC and don't create your ObserverServices inside it but as you say, inject IObserverService; therefore you'll be able to mock the services and test your VM without needing the whole service behavior.

I may suggest you to use Autofac or even Ninject. There are plenty of DI frameworks so look for the one that adjust to what you are looking for.

Comment: "There are plenty of DI frameworks". so why do you suggest " to use Autofac or even Ninject" specifically?

Comment: OP says "inject IObserverService" somehow. I'm only suggesting some of the most known DI. Is it even a problem?

Comment: sound like an overkill kind of problem. learning DI framework when trying to "learn using Observer" (OP comment) - meh

Comment: But if I inject IObserverService, I have no idea how to make instance of Observer with parameter: `new Observer1("name1")`

Comment: That's why I'm suggesting you to take a look at some DI framework. You may not use it and then create the ObserverService before, but your testing will depend on how you made it